# return result of foreach loop(s)

Tags: php, foreach, return

I have the some code which looks something like this (I've simplified it):

```
function process_something($a){
    foreach($a as $b){
        // Some logic here
        return $something;
    }
}
$input=[]; // An array of some kind
echo process_something($input);
```

I expect that final line to echo what the loops have returned but I get nothing. Maybe the above code will not work. I just put it in for illustration. I have a lot of nested loops working together to return various things.

If I have the loops echo data out, it works. However, I need this function to just return the end result to me for further processing, rather than echoing out to the user.

How do I proceed?

Comment: when calling `return`, the function ends... that is the nature of `return`

Comment: You know that this loop will only do once? At first loop he will get return from function.

Comment: Can you post actual example. It will be much easier to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case this loop will only run once, because `return` jumps out of a function on the first occurrence.

It should be more like:

```
function process_something($a){
    foreach($a as $b){
        $something = 'Some math or other logic here';
    }
    return $something;
}
$input=[]; // An array of some kind
echo process_something($input);
```

Please post your code, we will try to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: OK, this answers it for me. No need for me to post code as it gets really complex. To keep the code readable (it's HUGE!) I wanted to keep it as a series of loops and functions (which return data) but this could probably work. Or maybe I can get the functions to update another variable stored outside of the loops.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Karol, I had the same issue trying to return all the results of a loop. Now I know return has to be outside the loop, otherwise it'll jump out on the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect case for a [generator](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.generators.syntax.php), a concept that I rarely seen used.

```
  function process_something($a){
    foreach($a as $b){
      // Some logic here
      yield $something;
    }
  }

  $input=[]; // An array of some kind

  /**
   * The generator returns an Iterator instance
   * so you'd need to loop over it
   */
  foreach(process_something($input) as $item){
    // do stuff here
    // echo $item
    // echo $item->something
    // your call
  }
```

The major advantage here is that you can "return without actually returning", you're yielding a value and the generator continues on with it's work.

Not to mention it's very memory efficient, altough 99% of the times memory is not an issue.

AND, this is the nice part, you can apply specific logic **for each** of the items in the `$input` without needing to do some weird hack-ish function.

---

Alternatives

```
  function process_something($a){
    $return = [];

    foreach($a as $b){
      // Some logic here
      $return[] = $something;
    }

    return $return;
  }
```

---

The only reason this answer isn't a comment is that it's very rare that I see a question that would legitimately benefit from a generator. This is one of them.

---

More on generators:

http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/what-generators-can-do-for-you.html

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-php-generators

Comment: While Karol solved the problem for me, I think this is a good answer and something I need to look in to as I didn't know about `yield` at all.

Comment: It's fairly new, since PHP 5.6(I think), it's new only to PHP tho, other programming languages use generators on a regular basis, we're just following in their footsteps :D

Comment: To be honest, to use this, I will have to change parts of my code. At the moment, I've accepted Karol's answer because it has got things moving forward on my project but it will be worth using this approach in future once I need to clean everything up. It's an approach I wish I knew about before I started!

Answer (score 0):

I did get you properly . But I think you are looking for the last value of the array .
to do that just do it :

```
function process_something($a){
   $b = array_reverse ($a);
   return $b[0];
}
```

Comment: No, it's not that but thanks for the heads up on `array_reverse`!

Answer (score 0):

```
class StrHelper
{
    /**
     * Check for $string starts with $query
     * @param $string
     * @param $query
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function startsWith($string,$query){
        return substr($string, 0, strlen($query)) === $query;
    }
}

class ModelSearchHelper
{
    /**
     * filter  where $key of $data arr startsWith $modelName
     * @param string $modelName
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public static function searchFor(string $modelName,array $data){
// this code do same
//        $out=[];
//        foreach ($data as $key=>$value){
//          if(StrHelper::startsWith($key,$modelName)){
//                $out[$key]=$value;
//            }
//        }
//        return $out;
// of this
        return array_filter($data,function ($value,$key) use ($modelName){
            return StrHelper::startsWith($key,$modelName);
        },ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );
    }
}

$test=[
    'limit'=>10,
    'offset'=>5,
    'customer.name'=>'Fox',
    'customer.address.street'=>'forest st.'
];


//filter where $key of $model startsWith $modelName
var_dump(ModelSearchHelper::searchFor('customer',$test));
```

result:

```
array(2) {
  ["customer.name"]=>
  string(3) "Fox"
  ["customer.address.street"]=>
  string(10) "forest st."
}
```